# Using Intersect to copy data between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing an Excel macro (Excel 2016) to copy data between sheets.  Rather than use the typical Range command (for instance, Sheet2.Range("A1:A15").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A15").Value) I want to use Named Ranges for the Columns, in case I ever insert columns in either sheet in the future. I also want to use Intersect, in case I ever add/delete rows in the future.  I have been able to get this to work when I am copying data within the SAME worksheet, but it is giving me a "400 error" when I try to do it from one worksheet to another.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

First, here is a line of code that works when copying data within the same worksheet.

```
Intersect([P1B_CalcPercent1], Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value = Intersect([P1B_CalcPercent2], Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value
```

Here is my sub for trying to copy a range of cells from one sheet to another.  The line that begins with Intersect is giving me the 400 error.

```
Sub Copy_from_1A_Button()

Dim FirstRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Page 1B").Activate

Module7.UnprotectPage1BSheet

FirstRow = Range("B_first_row").Value
LastRow = Range("B_last_row").Value

If MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to do this? Data in the target cells will be overwritten.", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    Intersect([P1B_JobTitles], Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value = Intersect([P1A_JobTitles], Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value

End If

Module7.ProtectPage1BSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Both 'P1A_JobTitles' and 'P1B_JobTitles' are named ranges that have a scope of Workbook, but they exist on different sheets.  (Side question: would it matter if the scope of each was just the sheet it was on?)

I tried putting "Application." in front of Intersect in both places, but I got the same error.

Any ideas why the Intersect method isn't working to copy from one sheet to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because ROWS returns a Range object that represents all the rows on the specified worksheet. Because you aren't specifying a worksheet, it's just using the active sheet. You need to qualify it with the name of the worksheet you want to use it on. To do this dynamically, you can use something like this:

`Intersect(Range("SomeName"), Worksheets(Parent.Range("SomeName")).Rows("1:2")).Address`

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to get this to work, sort of.  I actually have multiple lines that begin with "Intersect", and changes I made to the first one worked fine:

Comment: `Intersect([P1B_JobTitles], Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value = Intersect([P1A_JobTitles], ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Page 1A").Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value`

Comment: However, on the next line, I am getting an error.  The error is: Object required.  Line is `Intersect([P1B_CalcPercent], Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value = Intersect([P1A_CalcPercent], ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Page 1A").Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value`

Comment: I have been staring at both lines trying to see what I have done wrong in the second line, but I'm not seeing it.  Any ideas?

Comment: If [P1B_JobTitles] or [P1B_CalcPercent] is scoped to a different sheet than the active sheet, you need to qualify it with the worksheets name, using something like `Worksheets(Parent.Range("SomeName")).Range("SomeName")`

Comment: I may have just figured it out.  P1A_CalcPercent and P1B_CalcPercent both have a scope of their particular sheet.  I have several of these that are scoped that way -- is there a way to edit the code so this line would work, or would I need to go into the Name Manager and change the scope to all of these to Workbook scope?

Comment: Hey Jeffrey.  Seems we posted at the same time!  Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: I'll have a play with scope, and come back with something shortly. Not sure if the above comment from me is going to cut it as is.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-named-ranges ...for locally scoped names, you need to add the sheetname into the name string i.e.  [SomeSheet!SomeName]. This makes it tricky to do 'dynamic' referencing like I was doing in my comment above, because VBA can't work out which sheet a name belongs to without iterating through all names in all sheets. Maybe simpler you change names to global scope, so you can use my approach above. Any reason why you're using locally scoped names?

Comment: I created some of these Named Ranges about two weeks ago.  Honestly, not sure why I did it that way.  I'm pretty new to using Named Ranges, so I didn't really know which I should do.  As for your suggestion, it worked!  This is how I changed the line to make it work: `Intersect([P1B_CalcPercent], Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value = Intersect(['Page 1A'!P1A_CalcPercent], ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Page 1A").Rows(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).Value`   Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Cool. Please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
dim i as long, j as long, pa as string, pb as string, P1A_P1B as variant
dim p1a as worksheet, p1b as worksheet

P1A_P1B = array("P1__JobTitles", "P1__CalcPercent")
set p1a = ThisWorkbook.workSheets("Page 1A")
set p1b = ThisWorkbook.workSheets("Page 1B")
...

for i=lbound(P1A_P1B) to ubound(P1A_P1B)
    pa = replace(P1A_P1B(i), "__", "A_")
    pb = replace(P1A_P1B(i), "__", "B_")
    with Intersect(p1a.Range(pa), p1a.Range(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow))
        Intersect(p1b.Range(pb), p1b.Range(FirstRow & ":" & LastRow)).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .Value
    end with
next i
...
```